# MySQL junction table concatenation

Tags: mysql

I have an requirement to return all educators associated with a session as a concatenated list, but to do it within a join (don't ask - I know there are multiple ways of doing it but I'm working with a library that won't accept those methods ;-))

I have a `sessions` table with `session_id` and `session_name`.

```
| session_id | session_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | Swimming     |
| 2          | Chess        |
```

I have a `session_educators` table which is basically a junction table `session_id` and `contact_id`.

```
| session_id | contact_id |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | 1          |
| 1          | 2          |
| 2          | 3          |
| 2          | 4          |
```

I have a `contacts` table with `contact_id` and `full_name`

```
| contact_id | full_name    |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | Fred Bloggs  |
| 2          | Mary Bloggs  |
| 3          | Mark Smith   |
| 4          | Shelly Smith |
```

So far this seems to be the closest I've come:

```
SELECT
    sessions.session_id,
    sessions.name,
    educators.names
FROM
    `sessions`
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(contacts.full_name SEPARATOR ', ') as names
        FROM
            `contacts`
        WHERE
            contact_id 
        IN 
            (
                SELECT
                    contact_id
                FROM
                    session_educator
                WHERE
                    session_educator.session_id = sessions.session_id
            )
    ) `educators`
USING
    (`session_id`)
```

But I'm really fumbling in the dark trying to figure it out, can anyone help?

What I'm wanting, as you can probably tell from the query, is a result like this:

```
| session_id | session_name | educators                |
+------------+--------------+--------------------------+
| 1          | Swimming     | Fred Bloggs, Mary Bloggs |
| 2          | Chess        | Mark Smith, Shelly Smith |
```

Any help greatly appreciated - even if it's just to say it can't be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you're making it all a little more complex than needed (unless I've missed something in your requirements? I know how much of a pain libraries can be...)

**This worked for me:**

```
SELECT
    session_id,
    session_name,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(full_name SEPARATOR ', ') as names
        FROM
            contacts c,
            session_educators se
        WHERE
            c.contact_id = se.contact_id
        AND
            se.session_id = s.session_id
    )
FROM
    sessions s
;
```

Comment: Thank you also, also works a treat. I do so love stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need subqueries for this.  It is a few joins and an aggregation:

```
select s.session_id, s.session_name,
       group_concat(e.name separator ', ') as educators
from sessions s left join
     session_educators se
     on se.session_id = s.session_id left join
     educators e
     on e.educator_id = se.educator_id
group by s.session_id;
```